Confusion about commutator between $R$-symmetry and supercharges in SUSY
The $R$-symmetry is the symmetry transforming different supercharges $Q_{\alpha}$ in a theory with supersymmetry into each other. So my understanding is that the generators of $R$, $T_a$, act on the vector space of $Q_\alpha$’s, but the $Q_{\alpha}$’s act on a different vector space, the space of superfields.
If that is the case, what is the meaning of $[T_a,Q_{\alpha}]$, or more precisely, the meaning of $Q_{\alpha}T_a$? I am confused because I don't see why a $T_a$ can act on a superfield. Or, if they are vectors belonging to different vector spaces, how can they belong to the same algebra?

Let us take the case of a single hypercharge $Q$. Here the symmetry is $U(1)$, and we have a single generator $R$. But $R$ is not the generator of the $U(1$) symmetry on the space of $Q$, rather, it is the version of the generator acting in hilbert space.
If $R$ was the generator of $U(1)$, then it should commute with $Q$, because in such case $Q'=e^{i\phi}Q$, then $R=i$, the imaginary unit, which does commute with $Q$.
Instead, $R$ is defined as:
\begin{align} 
e ^{ i R \phi } Q   e ^{ -i R \phi } & = e ^{  i \phi } Q   \\ 
\left( 1 + i R \phi + ... \right) Q   \left( 1 - i R \phi - ... \right) & = Q+ i \phi Q  + ...  \\ 
i\phi \left[ R     , Q \right]  =  i \phi Q   \\ 
\left[ R   , Q \right] =  Q   
\end{align}
The reason for the definition above is the following:
You want an operator that acts on the states $|\psi \rangle$ that keeps the expectation value invariant under R symmetry transformations, that is:
$\langle\psi| Q |\psi \rangle=\langle\psi'|e^{i\phi}Q |\psi' \rangle$
where $|\psi' \rangle =e ^{ i R \phi }|\psi \rangle$
Also:
$\langle\psi| Q |\psi \rangle= \langle\psi| e ^{ -i R \phi } e ^{ i R \phi }Q e ^{ -i R \phi }e ^{ i R \phi }|\psi \rangle=\langle\psi'|  e ^{ i R \phi }Q e ^{ -i R \phi }|\psi' \rangle$
Thus,
$e ^{ i R \phi } Q   e ^{ -i R \phi }  = e ^{  i \phi } Q $

The notation you use, where the action of the symmetry on an operator is implemented by a commutator implies that you are studying the quantum theory, as opposed to say the classical field theory of superfields.
With this in mind, it is easiest to think of the of two separate set operators, $\mathcal{Q_{\alpha}}^{A}$  and ${\mathcal{T}_a}$, which act on the Hilbert space. In the quantum theory, the chiral superfield $\Phi(y,\theta)$ is also an operator, which acts on the Hilbert space. However, we may deduce the action of a symmetry on an operator by requiring that every operator map a state in the Hilbert space to another state that lies within the Hilbert space.
$$
 |\psi_2\rangle= \mathcal{O}|\psi_1\rangle, $$ $$e^{i\mathcal{T}_am^{a}}|\psi_2\rangle = \left(e^{i\mathcal{T}_am^{a}} \mathcal{O}e^{-i\mathcal{T}_am^{a}}\right) e^{i\mathcal{T}_am^{a}}|\psi_1\rangle =  \mathcal{O'}e^{i\mathcal{T}_am^{a}}|\psi_1\rangle.
$$
$$|\psi'_2\rangle= \mathcal{O'}|\psi_1'\rangle.$$
At this stage, we recognize that the symmetry is unitarily realized on the Hilbert space only if each operator is also transformed.
We can now expand the new operator $\mathcal{O'}$ in $m^a$ and find
$$\delta O=[\mathcal{T}_a,O].$$
This is true for any operator $\mathcal{O}$. Choosing $\mathcal{O}=\mathcal{Q}_\alpha^A$ gives us the transformation of the super-symmetry generator (which is itself a symmetry operator) under R symmetry, while $\mathcal{O}=\mathcal{\Phi}(y,\theta)$ gives us the more conventional, classical field theory notion of the transformation of a fundamental (super) field under a symmetry tranformation.

Thanks for your answer. But you are assuming what I actually asked, why can you assume that the $T_a$'s  (or their exponentials) act on Hilbert or Fock space, if they are defined as acting on the supercharge operators. How can you do that? What is the meaning of $e^{i\mathcal{T}_am^{a}}|\psi\rangle $ if $e^{i\mathcal{T}_am^{a}}$ is not defined to act on $ |\psi\rangle$?

This is what it means to be linear operator. A map from a vector space to another (in this case the same vector space). The "definition" of R symmetry acting on supercharges acting is made in a classical field theory (in super space). Promoting this classical field theory to a quantum field theory involves computing the Dirac braket in the standard fashion and promoting it to a (anti) commutator. The algebra of operators in any quantum theory is inherited from the Bracket structure of the classical field theory--provided there are no anomalies.
